# JCE generated keys in Keysafe / nCipher

Tags: encryption-symmetric, jce, hsm

I am following the nCipher example to store symmettric keys in HSM and use from java program.

```
 KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "nCipherKM");
 SecretKey k = kg.generateKey();
 ks.setKeyEntry("MyAESKey", k, null, null);
```

Then I call below methods to save the key in security world. I am told I should be able to see them in KeySafe.

```
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("keystore.dat");
  ks.store(out, null);
  out.close();
```

I end up with two keys in KeySafe instead of one, and key names have nothing to the with the alias I used.

key_jcecsp_4912eadb0f19581317f02ce427b5f1ca3c872ef3-key-bb6328f32b6fbcae5787dde37640b37eb02ed97e

and

key_jcecsp_4912eadb0f19581317f02ce427b5f1ca3c872ef3

I have three questions:

1. Even though I gave a nice alias such as "MyAESKey" the key shows up with a long oid of some sort. How can I get it to appear with a proper name in KeySafe?
2. Why do I get 2 entries instead of one? Which one is the key?
3. What is the significance of "keystore.dat" - why am I not interfacing directly with the key files under C:\ProgramData\nCipher\Key Management Data\local ?

Thanks!

Vedat

Answer (score 2):

Vedat,

KeySafe doesn't know about JCE (which is ironic as it is itself a Java program).  It shows you the underlying objects in the Security World.  You're getting one actual key file containing your key data (encrypted by the HSM master key) and the plaintext alias ("MyAESKey"), and one file representing the KeyStore.  If you open up your keystore.dat file with a text editor, you'll see that it contains an identifier that shows up in the filename of the other files: this is how the software ties things together.

The files in Key Management Data\local are completely abstracted away by the JCE KeyStore API implementation: all you need to reference the keys in a KeyStore is the file for it: keystore.dat in your example.